# Natural join question, I have the answer, but I don't know why it's correct. Help?

Tags: database-design, join

[image: Schema of database]

[image: Answer]

So I have a relatively simple database schema. I'm not sure why the where clause in the answer magically makes the dept_name duplication problem go away. I'm new to all this and I'm sure the answer is very obvious but it's just not clicking for me at the moment. Can someone explain? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered by looking in how NATURAL JOINS works.

Natural join looks for same-named columns in two tables and joins the records of the two tables using these columns.

- The columns datatypes must match
- If there is more than one same-named column the result will be a cartesian join or an error
- If the joined rows have the same name but have no "logical" relations then the result won't be what was first expected. Exemple: Instructor's ID and Teaches's ID, those columns mean nothing to each other yet they are used by the natural join to connect the records.

The problem is you want to map different named columns together and you're using a natural join.

The solution is to be more explicit and use a regular JOIN such as SELECT * FROM instructor i JOIN teaches t on  i.ID=t.teacher_ID; (even though this column does not exists in this case, there must be one of those column that are matching if you look into the data)